# Application locked by "await"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, winrt-xaml

I am using async method as extension for StorageFile to return file's size. Problem is, this method deadlocks somehow my Windows Store app. Issue is within awaiting result from file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync. I am not very experienced in asynchronous programming, but I supposed await statement is there to prevent such situations. Does anyone see something obvious what I don't get?

Deadlock do not occur in debug, if I wait for some time with GetBasicPropertiesAsync.

Method:

```
    public static async Task<string> GetSizeMB(this StorageFile file)
    {
        var properties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        double sizeDouble = Convert.ToDouble(properties.Size) /1000000;

        return $"{Math.Round(sizeDouble, 2)} MB";
    }
```

Thanks in advance for hints.

Comment: Have you tried using `await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();.ConfigureAwait(false);`? That'll make sure that the task runs in the background thread, and does not marshal to the UI thread.

Comment: Show how you are calling the Extension method. Make use you are not mixing async and sync calls.

Comment: Probably @Demitrian is right - you are locked in UI thread, so you should run the extension in different context using Task.Factory.StartNew .

Answer (score 1):

If you look further up your call stack, you're almost certainly calling a task's `Result` or `Wait` member from the UI thread. This is not permitted on Windows Store applications, since it can freeze the UI thread.

I describe [this kind of deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in detail on my blog, but the summary version is as follows:

When `await` has to (asynchronously) wait, by default it will first capture a "context". This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. Later, when the (asynchronous) wait is complete, the remainder of your `async` method continues executing *on that captured context*.

In this case, the context is the UI `SynchronizationContext`. Further up your call stack, another method calls `GetSizeMB` and gets back a task, and then (presumably) calls `Result` or `Wait` on that task. This is the actual cause of the deadlock, because that code is *blocking* the UI thread until `GetSizeMB` completes. But `GetSizeMB` cannot complete because it needs to resume executing on the UI thread.

The proper fix is to replace `Result`/`Wait` with `await`.